# CSS select hidden elements

Tags: jquery, css, selector, hidden

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this annoying problem, as far as I know there isn't a :hidden selector in CSS, but you can use it in jQuery. The only other selector I know of in css is :empty, however my elements may not always be empty, but still be hidden.

So here's what I'm trying to do.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="one"></div>
     <div class="two"></div>
 </div>
```

I want to be able to select "one" or "two" and if it's currently hidden, I want to do something to the other element which is not.

like:

```
.wrapper .one:hidden .wrapper .two
```

I know I could do this with jQuery, however I would like to figure out a way that would automatically adjust based on whether or not the hidden element changes to visible, vice versa.

Comment: Give it a "hidden" class when it's hidden.  Then work with `.hidden`.

Comment: you can use visibility:hidden; ??

Comment: @Madbreaks It may come down to it that I will have to do something like that, but that would create more coding for me to add and remove that class, as with css if there were a :hidden function it would do it automatically. I'm just trying to cut down on code if I am able to.

Comment: @Dylan Cross: See my answer below, hope your are looking for [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11999731/1516616)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a hidden selector for css but in the meantime, you can add a class probably hidden?

`.wrapper .one.hidden`

Comment: It may come down to it that I will have to do something like that, but that would create more coding for me to add and remove that class, as with CSS if there were a :hidden function it would do it automatically. I'm just trying to cut down on code if I am able to.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in pure CSS in principle. If CSS would allow this then ["the first woodpecker that came along would destroy civilization"](http://www.murphys-laws.com/murphy/murphy-technology.html).

Consider something like:

```
.wrapper .one:not(:hidden) .wrapper .one { display:none; }
```

This creates perfect infinite loop. Your browser will die trying to solve it.

If it is interesting you can [read my article](http://www.terrainformatica.com/2008/07/css-selectors-and-computational-complexity/) on the subject.

Comment: True, however I'm sure they could add a maximum times it can be run or something along those lines, it would just make simple things like this far simpler. ha.

Comment: @DylanCross it is not about how many times this will run but rather about undetermined result. Will `.wrapper .one` be visible in my sample above?

Comment: I see. Well in the example above it's just the cut down absolute basics as to what I'm actually doing, "one" and "two" could both be hidden, or either one could be hidden, or both could be visible. It would depend on different things. (which is why it would take a little bit of code to make it all work, and keep it accurate as the page can change at any time (with ajax pushed data and such)

Comment: Ok, as there is no such feature in pure CSS then you will need to find other means to do so. For example dumb `window.setTimeout( checkIfThoseIsVisible());`. Such polling is not that effective but in some cases is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the complete list of CSS selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).  Unfortunately, there are none that apply to visibility or select by current CSS style.

The way that will involve the least code would be to give them both a `visible` class, which you could style in CSS.  Then use jQuery to remove the `visible` class whenever the element gets hidden, and add it when it becomes visible again.  Not very streamlined, but it seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZpAa/)

Instead of searching for the one that's hidden and do something to the other one, why not just search for the one visible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.wrapper div').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
          //do something special
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: ultimately this is the direction it looks like I'll have to do this, however the only problem, and the main problem of my question is that this will only do this when the page is first loaded, my page is completely full of ajax loaded content (realtime data pushed to the page), so it needs to do that when things change, if CSS had :hidden built in it would just be as simple as .one:hidden, however it doesn't so it'll take loads of code that will have to do checks each time it changes :\

Comment: It will run once because it's in the document.ready function but you can just create a regular function and call that function when the ajax call is successful. That way you don't repeat unnecessary code. If you don't want to check if an element visible using jQuery, the I would suggest going with classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DgqaL/)

**jQuery:**

```
if($('.one').is(":hidden")) {
   $(".two").css("color","red")    
}​
```